# PHP format punctuation with correct definitions

Tags: php, html-entities

Is there a PHP function / procedure that would take punctuation in a form such as commas, explanation marks, pound signs, quotation marks etc.. and reformat them with their correct html definitions.

```
eg. £ to become &pound;
```

Comment: I do believe that this is what you want: [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) which replaces only five characters (`&`, `"`, `'`, `<`, `>`):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

OR  [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) which replaces all input:

```
echo htmlentities($str);
```

Comment: More likely `htmlentities()`, as `htmlspecialchars()` only replaces `&`, `"`, `'`, `<`, and `>`.

Comment: @Wiseguy You are correct. The first replaces only the 5 characters, while the second replaces all input.

Comment: ...or at least [all characters with a named entity in HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) + single quotes, optionally.